# Problem with reinstalling albert on Ubuntu 20.04, how to fix invalid key resource URL error?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, launcher, gnupg

I want to reinstall the [albert launcher](https://albertlauncher.github.io/) on Ubuntu 20.04 after it stopped working for some reason. However, I am receiving an error when adding the public key. I am following the [official instructions](https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/installing/) and, after executing the first line, receive the following error in the terminal:

```
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.YUcCLYHPC4/home:manuelschneid3r.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 1488EB46E192A257: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 78414460095F1873: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 83FBA1751378B444: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 9BDB3D89CE49EC21: 4 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D530E028F59EAE4D: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D530E028F59EAE4D: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D530E028F59EAE4D: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 42
gpg:       skipped new keys: 42
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Author here. See [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/1731392/albert-repository-gpg-key-issues-on-debian-derivates/1731393) on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure exactly what caused my problem but deleting a gpg associated .asc file solved it for me.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschneid3r.asc
```

This solution was found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246031/gpg-invalid-key-resource-url-following-docker-official-guide)

I was then able to follow the [official Ubuntu 20.04 instructions](https://albertlauncher.github.io/docs/installing/) in order to install [albert](https://albertlauncher.github.io/).