# "gpg: invalid key resource URL" or "gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data" following official ROS Melodic installation guide

Tags: ros

I'm following the [official guide](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) to install ROS Melodic.

And, in step 1.3, I got something similar to the following, by 3 of the 4 alternative paths:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654

Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Esk2aHFoQ2/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
gpg: key F42ED6FBAB17C654: public key "Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:hpcoder1.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 5606C8D03F9E5FB8: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 10
gpg:       skipped new keys: 10
```

In the other one I got:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ABFSlwnvVU/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by doing the following in my case:

```
sudo rm "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:manuelschnid3r.asc"
```

In your case, you can go to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` check if the file `home:hpcoder1` 's extension is `.asc` or `.gpg` and then delete it by:

```
suo rm "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:hpcoder1.gpg"
```

or

```
suo rm "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home:hpcoder1.asc"
```

then you try this again and it'll work well:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 'hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80' --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

I refered to [gpg: invalid key resource URL following Docker official guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246031/gpg-invalid-key-resource-url-following-docker-official-guide)